# Issues with AWS Route53 setup for Multi Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have two different applications deployed through Elastic Beanstalk:

1. Single instance tomcat prebuild
2. Single instance multi docker

For App #1 I have route53 setup in a way that www.domain.com is an A record aliasing the EBS environment url and everything works perfectly.

I was trying to do the same for App #2, but it was not resolving to anything (even through direct environment url works fine).
Then I followed these instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/webapp/expanding-environments.html?icmpid=docs_eb_console_new#expanding-environments-domain to setup manually through CNAME record as following:
[image]
And after more than 24 hours nothing happening.

How can I debug this issue? How do I know what is the problem?

**UPDATE**

If I am trying to test record set it seem to be resolving to the right place:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was not very smart of me.
Apparently, the nameservers did not match between the domain and hosted zone. I set them to be the same, and everything started to work.